# Как отключить автоматический перенос курсора ввода на следующую строчку в VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Подскажите пожалуйста, какой из параметров нужно отключить в настройках, чтобы VS Code не переносил курсор ввода на следующую строчку спустя 1 секунду с момента как ты перестал вводить?

Я уже все параметры дважды изучил - ничего подобного не нашёл.

Comment: по умолчанию такого поведения не задумано. Одно из расширений балуется. Можете привести список ваших расширений? Чтобы не перебирать вручную, введите команду `code --list-extensions`

Comment: Спасибо за наводку с расширениями. Оказывается это из-за EditorConfig for VS Code. Осталось только понять, как отучить его это делать =)

Comment: По опыту лучше всего найти новое расширение, удобное для вас. Либо спросить на гитхабе от этой проблеме в репе расширения во вкладке `issue`, если нет решения или настройки, то менять

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за оперативную помощь!

Comment: На здоровье, пользуйтесь)

Comment: Ребята, спасибо огромное! Вы меня просто спасли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не дождался ответа, на комментарий, поэтому погадаю на кофейной гуще.

Такое может происходить по двум причинам

1. логика расширения
2. стоит автосохранение + стоит форматирование при сохранении

Первую причину без вмешательства ТС не понять. А вот по второй можно сказать либо отключить автосохранение, либо отключить форматирование при сохранении. Я склоняюсь больше ко второй опции, т.е. отключить форматирование при сохранении.

Делаем:

1. Открыть `Command Palette`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Ввести `Preferences: Open User Settings`
3. В строке поиска настроек ввести `Format on save`
4. Снять галку с настройки.

А чтобы форматировать документ, то можно использовать горячии клавиши, по умолчанию обычно <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. Либо заглянуть в настройки горячих клавиш и подсмотреть там

Answer (score 1):

Автор написал, что у него установлено расширение EditorConfig for VS Code. У меня такое же расширение и такая же проблема. В моих файлах проекта есть файл с настройками .editorconfig, в котором есть следующие настройки:

```ini
root = true

[*]
charset = utf-8
end_of_line = lf
indent_size = 2
indent_style = space
insert_final_newline = false
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

За автоматический перенос строки отвечает `insert_final_newline = false`. Как видите, у меня эта настройка уже установлена как `false` и проблема автоматического переноса курсора разрешилась.

Если у вас нет такого файла в проекте, то просто создайте его и укажите `insert_final_newline = false`.

Comment: Хм.. Я правильно понимаю, что проблема была только при написании в последней строке? Может просто в ней писать не надо? ;)